# How to stop a thread in my unmanaged DLL made in C#

Tags: c#, dll, thread-safety

I have a C# DLL that starts a thread for polling an USB device. My problem is that the `workerObject` and `workerThread` in the `StopListenUSB` function are `null`.

```
public class USBDevice
{
   private Worker workerObject;
   private Thread workerThread;

   public void StartListenUSB(int hwnd, uint wm_USER_KEYBOARD)
   {
      workerObject = new Worker();
      workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
      workerThread.Start();
   }

   public void StopListenUSB()
   {
      workerObject.RequestStop();
      workerThread.Join();
   }
}

public class Worker
{
   private volatile bool _shouldStop;

   public void RequestStop() { _shouldStop = true; }

   public void DoWork()
   {
      while (!_shouldStop)
      {...}
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you holding onto your instance of USBDevice?  As long as you are keeping a reference to it, you should be able to call StartListenUSB and then call StopListenUSB without issue.

Comment: adding to Pedro comment, are you referencing a new instance of this class to call the stop?

Comment: What do you mean by an "unmanaged DLL made in C#"? C# is a managed language. Is there a C++ DLL in the project that is creating a thread? (Or was that just a typo?)

Comment: If `workerObject` and `workerThread` are both `null` when `StopListenUSB` is called, then there's a bug in your program. Are you sure that `StartListenUSB` was called? Are you sure that it didn't throw an exception? Is something else in your program setting `workerObject` and `workerThread` to `null`?

Comment: I found the solution for this problem, static is needed when defining  private static Worker workerObject; private static Thread workerThread;